# How & where to use Web API2 along with MVC 5 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-web-api2, strongly-typed-dataset

I am coming from MVC development background and I do understand Web Api concept however I am struggling to understand that where I need to use Web Api if for example I am working on MVC application.

Do I not need any more MVC i.e MVC controller, Razor code, strongly typed data binding, if I am building application in Web API?

I want to understand MVC application along with Web API; from architectural point of view

I have fresh project and how should I go about using Web API in it.

Many Thanks

Comment: There is a significant overlap between MVC5 and Web Api and this is why they have been "merged" in MVC Core. My rule of thumb is use MVC controllers for HTML and Api controllers for returning serialized data such as JSON and XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s a tricky question, you know? But I’ll try to give my opinion, driven by my experience on the development of different applications and services using those two frameworks.

I believe that the most significant difference between those two frameworks lies behind their design goals: MVC was conceived (and has traditionally been used) for building *web sites* while Web API was born as a framework for building *services*.

### MVC

MVC excels in building web sites and web applications that use a *traditional interaction* model, based on web browsers as clients, synchronous interactions (with no, or little AJAX) and HTML as primary presentation language (that’s why we usually return Views inside controllers).

From an architectural point of view, MVC could be seen as a framework that spans across Presentation and Service layers: it can build a service that is already a web application through an interface strictly driven by populated Views. While this application type could be defined interoperable by a higher point of view, it surely remains bounded to a single kind of client (the Web Browser).

### Web API

Web API, instead, is explicitly designed to be a framework for building *services*, with many concepts inherited from what we learned implementing **Web Services** and **SOA** in the past. Its purpose is to allow a wide range of different devices and clients to consume a service over HTTP. It does not restrict access to only web browsers, but can easily be used as an abstraction layer (the Service Layer mentioned before) between any client application (mobile app, SPA, even other independent services) and the backend/business logic, without losing all the architectural and interoperability benefits given by REST principles and the HTTP protocol.

Web API excels when combined with client-side frameworks like AngularJS, React, Backbone, because it becomes the engine behind data and business logic, allowing those frameworks to create a more fluid and asynchronous interaction between the user and the whole application.

While may be arguable that MVC could be used for such purpose, is undeniable that it was not designed to be a framework for building services consumed by different kinds of clients.

### Aren’t they the same?

If we look at the internal architecture of those two frameworks we may find many things and choices in common. This is the main reason why many people do not find a clear distinction between them. In the near future (they are in beta right now) they will be merged into a single framework (MVC6) in ASP.NET Core.

### When use them together

In my opinion, there are not many use cases that will require you to use both MVC and Web API in a single project. The reason behind this is related to the different approaches taken in UI rendering: in a MVC Web Application pages are rendered server-side, using a strongly typed `ViewModel`, while delegating small parts of the rendering to AJAX calls (but those should not be the majority, or else you will find you are asking too much to the framework).

In a modern Web Application that leverage the use of REST services (such as the ones created using Web API) the UI is rendered (almost) entirely client-side, so the need of server-side rendering/model binding is next to nothing: you will compose your UI combining server data (e.g. in JSON format) with static assets (HTML, CSS3, JavaScript) on the client.

Combining the two frameworks could be useful when you need to provide a Web Application in a traditional manner (using MVC), but you also require to offer your services to external clients: your users will use your MVC app, while other services will use the Web API endpoint (similar to what Facebook, Twitter, etc. do).

Another example could be an hybrid approach, where you render part of your web site server-side (using Razor) while the *most dynamical* section of your site are served using AJAX calls to Web API endpoints (e.g. auto-completes fields, asynchronous calls). But, frankly, I think this could lead to useless complications, and I would stick to MVC (that could return JSON objects if required) if the AJAX calls are not that many.

#### TL;DR

If you need to build dynamic server-side *web sites* go for MVC. If you need to build *rich web applications* consumed by heterogeneous clients (SPAs, mobile apps, etc.) then go for Web API. At last, use both if you want to expose your services to independent external consumers but want to consume them yourself using less layers of abstraction.

More:
[On The Coexistence of ASP.NET MVC and WebAPI](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/07/01/on-the-coexistence-of-asp-net-mvc-and-webapi.aspx)
[ASP.NET Web API vs. ASP.NET MVC “APIs”](http://encosia.com/asp-net-web-api-vs-asp-net-mvc-apis/)

Answer (score 1):

Web API is simply a service which works on HTTP protocol and can consumed by any device which operates on HTTP protocol including mobile applications.. if you want to use it in your web project then I suggest to use it in all your listing pages.. Make a ApiController and code all the listing page functions in it then on the cshtml page.. call the web api controller by use of Ajax, you can use Angular also to build your listing pages.. this would be good exercise for you.. at least it worked for me.

Comment: what about MVC application... where should I use togather?

Comment: I was talking about MVC application, in your mvc web application you will surely have listing pages.. that is the place where you can use Web Api so this application will be a combination of both.